# Are the two B model constructions equivalent?

Tags: mirror-symmetry, mp.mathematical-physics, ag.algebraic-geometry

Now we have two B model constructions: Kontsevich-Baranikov (for genus 0) and Costello (for any genus). My question is, are they equal in genus 0? Or now which one is the one we want? Thanks!

Comment: I think this is not known...